# Speeding up program in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, numerical-methods, floating-accuracy, polynomials

I have 2 functions:

`ccexpan` - which calculates coefficients of interpolating polynomial of function `f` with `N` nodes in Chebyshew polynomial of the first kind basis.

`csum` - calculates value for arguments `t` using coefficients `c` from `ccexpan` (using Clenshaw algorithm).

This is what I have written so far:

```
function c = ccexpan(f,N)

z = zeros (1,N+1);
s = zeros (1,N+1);

for i = 1:(N+1)
    z(i) = pi*(i-1)/N;
end

t = f(cos(z));

for k = 1:(N+1)
    s(k) = sum(t.*cos(z.*(k-1)));
    s(k) = s(k)-(f(1)+f(-1)*cos(pi*(k-1)))/2;
end

c = s.*2/N;
```

and:

```
function y = csum(t,c)

M = length(t);
N = length(c);
y = t;
b = zeros(1,N+2);

for k = 1:M
    for i = N:-1:1
        b(i) = c(i)+2*t(k)*b(i+1)-b(i+2);
    end
    y(k)=(b(1)-b(3))/2;
end
```

Unfortunately these programs are very slow, and also slightly inacurrate. **Please give me some tips on how to speed them up, and how to improve accuracy.**

Comment: Have you profiled your code?

Comment: @AnderBiguri no, I don't know what is it, I'm new to matlab.

Comment: It generates a report, telling you where the execution time is spent: https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html

Comment: @Daniel so the report says, that `csum` was running for 40s and `ccexpan` 271s, out of which 50s was "self time". So I guess I should optimise `ccexpan`?

Comment: I have speed up `ccexpan` (see edited question) by a half, but it's still far too slow

Comment: The report also allows you to see inside the funtion, and know inside it which parts take time. AT some point, if you are running things millions of times, that is slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where possible try to get away from looping structures. At first blush, I would trade out your first for loop of

```
for i = 1:(N+1)
    z(i) = pi*(i-1)/N;
end
```

and replace with

```
i=1:(N+1)
z = pi*(i-1)/N
```

I did not check the rest of you code but the above example will definitely speed up you code. And a second strategy is to combine loops when possible.

Comment: and how to do that when I'm indexing my matrices with this index? Or with nested loops? Could you please make an example of the other loop in ccexpan?

Comment: Can you provide an example of f and N that you pass? (I presume f is a function but without knowing the form of f, I am not sure of how to provide advice for converting the second loop in ccexpan).

Comment: I wrote what argument means at the beginning of the question - `f` is a function, and `N` is a scalar

Comment: Can you give me an example of the function f? (It is important to know whether f is returning a scalar or vector. And if it is returning a vector is it a column or row, etc.)

Comment: f is scalar, one variable function eg. f = @(x) 1/(1+15*x.*x)

Comment: hmmm. a little confused. As you have it z is a row vector with N+1 elements. So cos(z) would also be  row vector. But f shows element wise multiplication  and would also yield a vector.

Comment: sorry, I forgot about dot after `/`, the function should be `f = @(x) 1./(1+15*x.*x)`

Answer (score 0):

Martin,

Consider the following strategy.

```
% create hypothetical N and f
N = 3
f = @(x) 1./(1+15*x.*x) 

% calculate z and t
i=1:(N+1)
z = pi*(i-1)/N
t = f(cos(z))

% make a column vector of k's
k = (1:(N+1))'

% do this: s(k) = sum(t.*cos(z.*(k-1)))
s1 = t.*cos(z.*(k-1))    % should be a matrix with one row for each row of k
                         % via implicit expansion
s2 = sum(s1,2)           % row sum, i.e., one value for each row of k

% do this: s(k) = s(k)-(f(1)+f(-1)*cos(pi*(k-1)))/2
s3 = s2 - (f(1)+f(-1)*cos(pi*(k-1)))/2

% calculate c
c  = s3 .* 2/N
```

Comment: I think this carries you through the entire function.

Comment: If this works let me know and I'll clean up my entire posting to consolidate.

Comment: I don't know why, but unfortunately it works slighty slower.

Comment: Also, I have edited the question, apparently `csum` works faster with nested loops, for some reason.

Comment: You will need to provide/create a complete reproducible example (main program and all functions) to diagnose further. Nested loops should not be faster.

Comment: generally, the testing code is not mine, it is a precompiled code, but generally it calculates the time of the function `csum(t,ccexpan(f,N))` and compares speed with "model function" (it runs my funtion, and model function 20 times or so for large arguments, and then calculates the average time for both, the testing takes few minutes). For now, with nested loops, my function in 38% as fast as model function. The value of `N` and size of `t` is `32769` to be precise, and the `f` value used for testing is `@(x) sqrt(1-x.^2).^3`.

Comment: do you have any ideas? because I have to hand in the program today

Comment: sorry. no. my method results in needing to create a 32769x32769 matrix which > 5GB and doesn't fit in my memory without transitioning to tall arrays which is a road I have not learned how to do.

Comment: ok,  I guess I need to develop a better algorithm then . Thank you for help anyway.